# Instalar o habilitar "Instalar desde un directorio" en joomla 3.x

Tags: joomla3

Estoy montando una pag. web con joomla y necesito instalar una extensión, pero dicha extensión solo la puedo instalar desde el la opción "Instalar desde un directorio", pero esta opción no esta disponible. Alguien sabe como habilitarla o si requiero instalar una extensión para poder "Instalar desde un directorio".

Comment: ¿Qué versión exacta de Joomla?

Comment: Hola te comento, la versión que estoy usando es:
Joomla! 3.6.2 Stable [ Noether ] 4-August-2016 23:41 GMT

Answer (score 1):

Por lo general no viene activada por defecto en JOOMLA, tienes que ir a la siguiente pestaña:

Extensiones -> plugin -> BUSCAR instalador - instalar desde directorio -> activar el plugin.

Con eso podras instalar desde el directorio.